# Find the GS of the System of DE's $\begin{cases} x' = x-3y\\ y'=3x+7y \end{cases}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the GS of the following system of DE's where the independent variable is $t$ and $x$ and $y$ are the dependent variables

\begin{cases}
x' = x-3y\\
y'=3x+7y
\end{cases}

I know using eigenvalues and eigenvectors or operators is one way to do this. But I wish to double check my answer using a substitution method.

So my work:

The second DE $y'=3x+7y$ can be rewritten as $x = \cfrac{y'}{3}-\cfrac 73y$

then $x' = \cfrac{y''}{3}-\cfrac73y'$

When we plug these values of $x$ and $x'$ into the first DE ($x' = x -3y)$, we get with some rearranging

$\cfrac{y''}{3}-\cfrac83y'+\cfrac{16}{3}y = 0$

Which has a characteristic equation of

$\cfrac{r^2}{3}-\cfrac83r+\cfrac{16}{3} = 0$

with roots $r_1=4$ and $r_2 = 4$

Then the solution for $y$ is $y$ = $C_1e^{4t}+C_2te^{4t}$

Then we back sub to solve for $x$ using $x = \cfrac{y'}{3}$$-\cfrac73y$ with the solution of y we just found.

We get $x =-C_1e^{4t}-C_2te^{4t} + \cfrac{C_2}{3}e^{4t} =-C_1e^{4t}-C_2te^{4t} + C_3e^{4t}$

so the GS to the homo system is

\begin{cases}
x = -C_1e^{4t}-C_2te^{4t}+C_3e^{4t}\\
y = C_1e^{4t}+C_2te^{4t}
\end{cases}

If this solution is right, then I'm confident that I understand how substitution method works for solving DE systems. (Also it would boost my confidence in using the operator method to solve this as I got the same answer as this using the operator method). I'm a little thrown off on the roots being the same but I still think my methodology is still sound. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if I've got this right cause then I know I completely understand how to solve a system of DE's.

If more work is necessary to show please let me know.

Comment: You can always validate the correctness by substituting the result into each equation and seeing if it works. On the surface, the approach and result seem correct.

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
x = -C_1e^{4t}-C_2te^{4t}+C_3e^{4t}\\
y = C_1e^{4t}+C_2te^{4t}
\end{cases}$$
You should only end with two constants not three.
$$y=C_1e^{4t}+C_2te^{4t}$$
$$y'=4C_1e^{4t}+C_2e^{4t}+4tC_2e^{4t}$$
$$y'=4C_1e^{4t}+C_2e^{4t}(1+4t)$$
And since:
$$x = \cfrac{y'}{3}-\dfrac 73 y$$
You should only have $C_1$ and $C_2$ constant. You applied the method of substitution correctly.

Comment: Is there a problem with having 3 constants though? as $4C_2te^{4t}$ could be written as $C_3te^{4t}$ can it not? Is my answer not logically equivalent? If not why?

Comment: Yep there is a problem. Because it means you can choose three constants when it is not the case. You can only choose two constants. @BadwaterBarry  You can't change the constants. $C_2$ must stay the same. Rewrite the solution and keep the correct constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ then it's correct.

Comment: Thank You. I see my error AND I learned something new which is a big dopamine feeling. Many Thanks

Comment: You 're very welcomed @BadwaterBarry

Comment: Note that since your system of DE is equivalent to a second order differential equation as you showed in your solution and a second order DE has only two constants. It span a vectorial of dimension two... So only two constants are needed....On the other hand if you need to change a constant name you need to change all the occurrences of that constant. @BadwaterBarry

Answer (score 2):

Your method is correct.

Another way is to write the system as $X'=MY$

Where $M$ is the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -3 \\ 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}$$
its eigen values are $m_1,m_2=4$ (repeated roots), so the solution for $x$ can be written as
$x=(A t+B)e^{4t}$, putting it in first equation one can get $y$. So there will be two
undetermined constants: $A,B$.